# How to destruct the CComPtr when it is made as Member Variable for a Class?

Tags: c++, com, atl

How to destruct the CComPtr when it is made as Member Variable for a Class?

Following is the piece of Code I have written and m_piControl is the member variable CComPtr . 
I have assigned the value of m_piControl to rpControl and rpControl used further.

```
HRESULT CSession::GetInterface(OUT CComPtr<IControl>&   rpControl )
{
    if (m_piConSIControl == NULL)
    {
        CComPtr<IDispatch> pConDM;
        HRESULT hResult = GetMaintenance( &pConDM );
        if( FAILED( hResult ) )
            return hResult;

        CComQIPtr<IMaintenance> pMaintenance( pConDM );
        if( !pMaintenance )
            return E_NOINTERFACE;

        hResult = pMaintenance->GetControl( &m_piControl );
        if( FAILED( hResult ) )
            return hResult;
    }
    rpControl = m_piControl;
    return S_OK;
}
```

On Assignment, m_piControl refcount increase. But the release for m_piControl not getting called.
Should I call it explicitly?

Comment: m_piControl decrements its refcount when it is being destructed while non-empty. So if you do the handling in the rest of the code allright, there is no need to decrement in the destructor. Assuming you want to keep m_piControl around after this function finishes. You made it a member for a reason, right?

Comment: Yes.. I need it again and again. So made it as member variable. and I am creating it only for first time. But while returning, the assignment made is increasing its refcount. Will it be causing any problem?

Comment: No - as you pass the pointer out to someone else and you have no control over the life time this is exactly what should happen. It is the job of the caller to release when done with it.

Comment: There are *two* references, one held by your m_piControl variable and one held by the client code to which you returned the interface pointer.  It is your job to release your own reference, the client code cannot help.  The argument should *not* be a CComPtr<>, that's not what the calling code used.  It must be a plain IControl**.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
Actually t he problem was with the base class destruction.On destructing the base class properly, the ComPtr m_piControl will release its refcount properly and gets destroyed on own.

Answer (score 1):

Release of `m_piControl`'s COM interface pointer will happen when the [member] variable is destroyed, which in turn happens with destruction of the owner class instance. This does happen "automatically" and reference count is properly managed. That is, you don't need to release `m_piControl`'s value explicitly.

If you for whatever reason still want to release the interface pointer explicitly, you can at any time (provided that you comply with COM threading, of course) call `m_piControl.Release();`. For example, this might happen before you return `S_OK` in your code snippet.